# Similar library of Scapy for C++

Tags: python, c++, scapy

I want to know if Is there any library that let me do some packet crafting and sniffing in c++ ? Something like "Scapy" ,
i think it has a library in python .

Also i want to know which is better and more effective in network programming and building high-level network security tool , C++ or python ?

I am a moderate programmer in c++ but find python better and simpler than C++ in network realm ,is this true ?
thanks in advance

Comment: Unless you really need too eek out the performance Python will usually be better. For this particular task I'd say is better suited to Python.

Answer (score 10):

[libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/) is one similar library which can capture network traffic. [Libnet](http://libnet.sourceforge.net/libnet.html) is another library which you may use for crafting network packets.